# TreeTable inserting new item (Vaadin)

Tags: vaadin, treetable

I have a TreeTable and I could initialize it with elements, and they are shown. 
But much later I could not insert new elements.

- every treetable.addItem(...) gives null later
- the methods in the initialization can not insert new elements either later.
- every new item has an unique itemid
- i did not get any error message

How can I find out what is the real problem ?

I'm sure I added the proper types in the proper order.

Thanks in advance.

(insertion of code snippet would be boring long because we have 10 column)

Comment: you need to add the code for best understanding your question

Answer (score 3):

It's very hard to know what is wrong when you don't give any code but it could be that your table doesn't allow new objects. Use this method to change it

```
myTreeTable.setNewItemsAllowed(true)
```

Comment: I commented out  myTreeTable.setVisibleColumns ... line, then it works well ... later I will answer my question completely, when the system allows it.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed what was the "problem". After using setVisibleColumns I could not add new item.
as I commented it the new item could go into treetable.
Test it yourself (Vaadin 6.7.3-4)

```
    TreeTable tt = new TreeTable();
    mainWindow.addComponent(tt);

    tt.addContainerProperty("description", String.class, "");
    tt.addContainerProperty("keyword", String.class, "");
    tt.addContainerProperty("priority", String.class, "");

    tt.addItem(new Object[]{"0","k 0","p 0"},0);
    tt.addItem(new Object[]{"1","k 1","p 1"},1);
    tt.addItem(new Object[]{"2","k 2","p 2"},2);
    //tt.addItem(new Object[]{"3","k 3","p 3"},3);  //works well    

    tt.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] {"description","keyword"});       

    tt.addItem(new Object[]{"3","k 3","p 3"},3);    //doesn't work because of setVisibleColumns ....
```

Strange ...

Cs.